# Is it possible to get all errors after submit reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to dump all form control error after submit. Every time I have to check each single input just like

```
this.form.controls['client_id'].errors;
this.form.controls['student'].errors
```

This give single error. But I need all error in a single object like

```
{
  client_id: {
    'required': true
  },
  student: {
    'maxlength': {
      'requiredLength': 2,
      'actualLength': 6
    },
    'email': true
  }
}
```

I know angular provide some technique in form like `value`, `status`, `pristine` etc. But I dont find  any technique after submit to show all error object

Comment: You'll have to recursively walk the form to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As long as this functionality is not shipped with original library you can create a small sub-library that does that. What you need is to extend original classes that return you the errors.

```
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormGroup as OriginalFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

class FormGroup extends OriginalFormGroup {

  // create a getter allErrors
  // returns an object of sub-controls' errors
  get allErrors() { 
    return Object
      .keys(this.controls) // go through all the control names
      .reduce((result, name) => {
        const control = <FormGroup | AbstractControl>this.controls[name];

        // if control is FormGroup recursively call its `allErrors`
        if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
          result[name] = control.allErrors;
        } else if (control instanceof FormArray) {
          // add implementation for array here
        } else {
          // for normal controls add errors here
          result[name] = control.errors;
        }

        return result; // and return the result to the next control
      }, {});
  }

}
```

(probably you would want to also have *your* version of `FormArray` and `FormControl` as well)

And it's finally time to use it

```
import { FormGroup } from './my-forms';

this.form = new FormGroup() // all as usually but using your FormGroup

console.log(this.form.allErrors)
```

The implementation is not full and I'm not even sure you can use it as is, however it shows the way to deal with any customization of the native Angular reactive forms.